# How can I draw a cross section as in the figure below?

Tags: pgfplots

How can I draw a cross section as in the figure below?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried? What is this shape, do you have a parametrization for it? Why do you tag this pgfplots, do you have experience with this, or is there any reason why you prefer it to, say, asympote, plain Ti*k*Z or pstricks?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! with lot of experiences and patient. if you beginner, than is better to include this picture in your document with `\includegraphics{imae file name>}`. `pdflatex` beside `pdf` filres suport `png`, jpg` ... images formats.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a repeating question on this site, and since there are some statements with which I do not 100% agree, as a proof of concept: yes, one *can* draw such things with pgfplots. You only need to be a bit patient (or have a super fast computer). If you have more than one surface, two helpful (or even necessary?) ingredients are:

1. Do some 3D ordering by hand. (This is not necessary for patchplots but for these kind of plots it is, I think.)
2. Use layers.

The actual ordering for of the plots is not important, but the layers are.
What is meant by "3D ordering by hand" is perhaps best illustrated by an animation.

[image]

Notice that the strange lines on the animation are an artifact of the conversion to an animated gif. The actual pdf does not have the problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {3} %{1,2,3}%   % <-for animation
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\v}{0.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\u}{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={radius(\x)=sqrt(1.5^2-(\x-1.5)*(\x-1.5));
funky(\x)=(1+\v*cos(4*deg(\x)));},x={(3.2*\u cm,0.0cm)}, 
   y={(0cm,\u cm)},z={(-\u*0.3535cm,-\u*0.3535cm)},]
\begin{axis}[set layers,colormap/cool,hide axis,
   x={(3.2*\u cm,0.0cm)}, 
   y={(0cm,\u cm)},
   z={(-\u*0.3535cm,-\u*0.3535cm)},
   ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,xmin=-0.1,xmax=3
   ]
  \addplot3[draw=none] coordinates {(0.3,-2,-2) (0.3,2,-2) (0.3,2,2)
  (2.7,2,2) (2.7,2,-2) (2.7,-2,-2)};
  \path[name path=plane] (1.5,-2.25,-2.25) coordinate (z1)
  -- (1.5,-2.25,2.25) coordinate (z2) -- (1.5,2.25,2.25)  coordinate (z3)
  -- (1.5,2.25,-2.25) coordinate (z4) -- cycle;
  \draw[-latex] (0,-2.25,0) -- (3,-2.25,0) node[below left]{$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,-2.5,0) -- (0,2.5,0) node[below left]{$y$};
  \addplot3[smooth,opacity=0.3,surf,shader=interp,on layer=axis background,
  samples=30,
  domain=0.3:2.7,y domain=pi:2*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  (x,{cos(deg(y))*radius(x)*funky(y)}, 
  {sin(deg(y))*radius(x)*funky(y)});
  %
  \ifnum\X>1
  \path[on layer=main,thick,purple,fill=purple,fill opacity=0.3] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=0:2*pi]
  (1.5,{cos(deg(\x))*radius(1.5)*funky(\x)}, 
  {sin(deg(\x))*radius(1.5)*funky(\x)});
  \draw[on layer=axis background,thick,purple,purple,thick,dashed] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=pi:2*pi]
  (1.5,{cos(deg(\x))*radius(1.5)*funky(\x)}, 
  {sin(deg(\x))*radius(1.5)*funky(\x)});
  \draw[on layer=axis foreground,thick,purple,purple,thick] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=0:pi]
  (1.5,{cos(deg(\x))*radius(1.5)*funky(\x)}, 
  {sin(deg(\x))*radius(1.5)*funky(\x)});
  \draw[blue,thick,dashed,on layer=main,fill=blue!70!green,fill opacity=0.3] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=0:2*pi]
  (0.3,{cos(deg(\x))*radius(0.3)*funky(\x)}, 
  {sin(deg(\x))*radius(0.3)*funky(\x)});
  \draw[blue,thick,on layer=main,fill=blue!70!green,fill opacity=0.3] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=0:2*pi]
  (2.7,{cos(deg(\x))*radius(0.3)*funky(\x)}, 
  {sin(deg(\x))*radius(0.3)*funky(\x)});
  \fi
  %
  \ifnum\X>2
  \addplot3[smooth,opacity=0.3,surf,shader=interp,on layer=axis foreground,
  samples=30,
  domain=0.3:2.7,y domain=0:pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  (x,{cos(deg(y))*radius(x)*funky(y)}, 
  {sin(deg(y))*radius(x)*(1+\v*cos(4*deg(y)))});
  \path[thick,name path=upper] plot[smooth,variable=\x,samples=30,domain=0.3:2.7]
  (\x,{cos(deg(0))*radius(\x)*funky(0)}, 
  {sin(deg(0))*radius(\x)*funky(0)});
  \path[thick,name path=lower] plot[smooth,variable=\x,samples=30,domain=0.3:2.7]
  (\x,{cos(deg(pi))*radius(\x)*funky(pi)}, 
  {sin(deg(pi))*radius(\x)*funky(pi)});
  \path [name intersections={of=plane and upper,by={x1,x2}}];
  \path [name intersections={of=plane and lower,by={y1,y2}}];
  \draw (y1) -- (z2) -- (z3) -- (z4) -- (x2);
  \draw[dashed] (y1) -- (z1)  -- (x2);
  \fill (1.5,-2.25,0) circle(1pt) node[below] {$x$};
  \fill (0.3,-2.25,0) circle(1pt) node[below] {$a$};
  \fill (2.7,-2.25,0) circle(1pt) node[below] {$b$};
  \begin{scope}[on layer=main]
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=1.5,transform shape,xscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) {$A(x)$};
    \node at (1.8,1.8) {$P_x$};
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.3,transform shape,xscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) {$A(a)$};
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=2.7,transform shape,xscale=-1]
    \node at (0,0) {$A(b)$};
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \draw[on layer=axis foreground,thick,blue] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=0.3:2.7]
  (\x,{cos(deg(pi/4))*radius(\x)*funky(pi/4)}, 
  {sin(deg(pi/4))*radius(\x)*funky(pi/4)});
  \draw[on layer=axis background,thick,blue,dashed] 
  plot[smooth,samples=59,domain=0.3:2.7]
  (\x,{cos(deg(pi/4+pi))*radius(\x)*funky(pi/4+pi)}, 
  {sin(deg(pi/4+pi))*radius(\x)*funky(pi/4+pi)});
  \fi
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Notice that my 3D ordering is far from perfect. I split the domains up in `0:pi` and `pi:2*pi`. This is not entirely correct, but a reasonable approximation in this case. Note also that the `3d` library works without any problems here.

Comment: @user170061 Both the previous version and the updated version *do* compile.

Comment: @user170061 This just means you do not have the newest version installed. You can *try* to compile with `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` instead. Depending on the actual version in your installation it will or will not work. At a given point you may want to update your installation.

Comment: @user170061 Sorry, may I ask what *you* have done to produce the plot?

Comment: \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}